# App not showing up in Google Play

Tags: android

I published my app around 10-15 minutes ago, and it still isnt appearing in Google Play. I have tried to go to the direct page for the app, but that wont even come up. On the Google Developer Console, it says the app was published though. Anyone know what I should do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wait a little while :) Might take some time to propagate.

Answer (score 3):

Just wait :) My app was appeared in several hours after publishing. Your app will be here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yourapp.package

Comment: Will that link work right away or may still have to wait a few hours?

Comment: It appears there's a delay in getting to the details url too